# Change img to div with background, with jQuery

Tags: jquery, rounded-corners, dom-manipulation

I'd like to use jQuery to switch all img elements with a specific class to a div with background.
So that all:

```
<img class="specific" src="/inc/img/someimage.png" />
```

Becomes:

```
<div class="specificDiv" style="background: url(/inc/img/someimage.png); width: fromImageElementPX; height: fromImageElementPX;"></div>
```

I'd like to do this so that I can round the corners using css3.
The CMS user, customer, will only be able to insert IMG elements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I can think of:

```
$('.specific').replaceWith(function () {
    var me = $(this);
    return '<div class="specificDiv" style="background: url(' + me.attr('src') + '); width: ' + me.width() + 'px; height: ' + me.height() + 'px;"></div>';
});
```

Comment: +1 I don't think it's hard to read at all. Looks very clean to me.

Comment: works great! is there a way to resize the background image in the DIV to the DIV DOM size?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('img.specific').each(function(){ //iterate through images with "specific" class
    var $this = $(this), //save current to var
        width = $this.width(), //get the width and height
        height = $this.height(),
        img = $this.attr('src'), //get image source
        $div = $('<div class="specificDiv"></div>')
        .css({
            background: 'url('+img+')', //set some properties
            height: height+'px',
            width: width+'px'
        });
    $this.replaceWith($div); //out with the old, in with the new
})
```

Comment: I'd rather do `$div = $('<div></div>').setClass($(this).getClass()+'Div')`

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but I haven't tested it.

```
var origImage = $(".specific");
var newDiv = $("<div>").addClass("specificDiv");
newDiv.css("background-image", "url('" + origImage.attr("src") + "')");
newDiv.width(origImage.width()).height(origImage.height());
origImage.replaceWith(newDiv);
```

Comment: The last line should be origImage.replaceWith(newDiv).  Other than that... it works!

Comment: Also...another thing you can do is replace newDiv.css("width", origImage.width()).css("height", origImage.height());  with newDiv.width(origImage.width()).height(origImage.height());  - might make it a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/ozoji3/3/edit

```
$(function() {
  $("img.rounded").each(function() {
    var $img = $(this),
        src = $img.attr('src'),
        w = $img.width(),
        h = $img.height(),
        $wrap = $('<span class="rounded">').css({
            'background-image': 'url('+ src +')',
            'height': h+'px',
            'width': w+'px'
          });
    $(this).wrap($wrap);
  });
});
```

Comment: I like that you used `$.wrap()` instead of my `$.replaceWith()`.

Comment: Where's your answer? Don't link to the answer. Post the code here.

Comment: @patrick, Why? Is it not just as easy to click the link and test it?

Comment: The link is fine for testing, but you should include the solution as well (as you now did). That's the way SO works. Your solution is meant to be available to people 5 years from now, while the link may not be.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (taking the code from Andrew Koester), is to put it in a plugin.  Here's what it might look like...

```
$.fn.replaceImage = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    var origImage = $(this);
    var newDiv = $("<div>").attr("class", "specificDiv");
    newDiv.css("background", "url('" + origImage.attr("src") + "')");
    newDiv.width(origImage.width()).height(origImage.height());
    origImage.replaceWith(newDiv);  
  });
};
```

Then, to execute it, just call something like this...

```
$(".specific").replaceImage();
```